# Tailwind CSS default background colors not working

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is the code for an anchor element that I have on my website whose background color I want to be orange:

```
<a
    href="https://google.com"
    class="inline-flex items-center justify-center bg-orange-500 px-7 py-[14px] text-2xl text-center font-medium text-dark shadow-1 transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-2 hover:text-body-color"
      >
Get Started
  </a>
```

But currently with `bg-orange-500` in the class, the anchor's background is transparent and there is no mention of orange in the anchor's styles when I select it with inspect element. However, when I change the code to be `bg-white`, the button's background is white as expected.

This is my config:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.html", "./assets/**/*.js"],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "540px",
      // => @media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

      md: "720px",
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      lg: "960px",
      // => @media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

      xl: "1140px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

      "2xl": "1320px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1400px) { ... }
    },
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "16px",
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        black: "#212b36",
        "dark-700": "#090e34b3",
        dark: {
          DEFAULT: "#111928",
          2: "#1F2A37",
          3: "#374151",
          4: "#4B5563",
          5: "#6B7280",
          6: "#9CA3AF",
          7: "#D1D5DB",
          8: "#E5E7EB",
        },
        primary: "#3758F9",
        "blue-dark": "#1B44C8",
        secondary: "#13C296",
        "body-color": "#637381",
        "body-secondary": "#8899A8",
        warning: "#FBBF24",
        stroke: "#DFE4EA",
        "gray-1": "#F9FAFB",
        "gray-2": "#F3F4F6",
        "gray-7": "#CED4DA",
      },
      boxShadow: {
        input: "0px 7px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03)",
        form: "0px 1px 55px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)",
        pricing: "0px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
        "switch-1": "0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)",
        testimonial: "0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(92, 115, 160, 0.07)",
        "testimonial-btn": "0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(72, 72, 138, 0.08)",
        1: "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(166, 175, 195, 0.40)",
        2: "0px 5px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the project-relative file path of the file that the anchor tag resides in?

Comment: @Wongjn It's the index file, so the path is just index.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the file that the anchor tag is in is not covered by the `content` file globs in your Tailwind configuration. To have the `bg-orange-500` class (and other classes that only exist in this file) work, consider adding another entry to the `content` file globs for your `index.php`:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./*.html",
    "./assets/**/*.js".
    "./index.php"
  ],
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it still isn't working for me.

Comment: Consider checking the file that the anchor tag is **written** in is indeed `index.php`. Consider checking string concatenation has not been used to build the class name. Consider checking a Tailwind compilation has run since you made the configuration change. Consider checking whether your browser might be using a cached version of the CSS file.

Comment: I checked the first two things that they passed, but where do you see if a Tailwind compilation has run?

Comment: Check the created/modified timestamp of the CSS file it compiled. Otherwise, run a compilation now with the configuration change mentioned above to ensure it has run since the configuration change.